# Texmate 2 file browser is empty

Tags: textmate

This is probably quite a simple oversight on my part, but googling hasn't helped, so...

The file browser always appears empty in my installation of Textmate 2.

I thought it might be some problem with the include/exclude preference settings.  Right now they're

```
Exclude: {*.{o,pyc},Icon\r,CVS,_darcs,_MTN,\{arch\},blib,*~.nib}
Include: {.html,.tex,.txt,.tm_properties,.htaccess}
Non-text files: {*.{ai,bz2,gif,gz,icns,ico,jpg,jpeg,m4v,nib,o,pdf,png,psd,pyc,rtf,scssc,tar,tbz,tgz,tif,tiff,xib,zip},Icon\r}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The include pattern tells TextMate what you want included.

Set it to `*` to include everything (except hidden files). The default is: `{*,.tm_properties,.htaccess}` which includes all non-hidden files and additionally files named `.tm_properties` and `.htaccess` (which are normally hidden).

In your pattern, you have set it to only include 5 files.

I assume what you want is something like: `*.{html,tex,txt}`. Though by explicitly including these file types, you indirectly hide all other file types.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after messing up the settings.

To fix it, I just deleted:

`~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Global.tmProperties`